# Derivation of the inequality

Tags: inequality

For positive integer k, for any c>0, does there exist k_0>0 that depends on c, such that:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code that you have tried out so far in copy-pastable form.

Comment: Since $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You may use "ForAll" and "Reduce" like:

```
eq = {ForAll[k, k > k0, Sqrt[k] - c <= Sqrt[k - 1]], k0 > 0, c > 0};
Reduce[eq, k0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The condition "For positive integer k" is not of importance, this is true  for real values of `k` as

```
Resolve[ForAll[c, c > 0,  Exists[k0, ForAll[k,k > k0, Sqrt[k]-c <= Sqrt[k - 1]]]], Reals]
```

> `True`

shows.

Comment: I'd like to add that `Resolve[Exists[k0, 
  ForAll[k, k > k0, Sqrt[k] - c <= Sqrt[k - 1]]], Reals]` produces `c>0`.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[k, k > k0, Sqrt[k] - c <= Sqrt[k - 1]], Reals]` results in `(0 < c <= 1 && k0 >= (1 + 2 c^2 + c^4)/(4 c^2)) || (c > 1 && k0 >= 1)`.